Pasar datos de Jtextfiel a Jtable en diferentes JFrame Form
¿Como haría pasar pasar valores de un JTextfield a un JTable que estén en diferentes JFrame Form?
Me explico mejor quisiera crear dos JFrame donde en el primero puedan registrar datos y luego en el segundo los muestre en una tabla.

depende la estructura de tu JTable y sin código obviamente no podemos ayudarte
